# How to publish Office add-in to Marketplace?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office365-apps, marketplace, office-store

Has anything changed about the way we publish Office.js add-in to Office Store? I'm following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/add-in-submission-guide) (which is pretty recent) and in there they ask me to go to Partner Store, then **Office Store** tab and choose **New Offer** > **Office add-in**:

[image]

But in my Partner Center there is no **Office Store** tab. There is a **New Offer** dropdown but it doesn't contain **Office add-in** option.

[image]

I hear that they have merged the two (Marketplace and Office Store), but it doesn't seem to be the case right now. Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer from Microsoft support guys. Office Store enrollment is still separate from Marketplace enrollment. You must be enrolled in Office Store program to see Office add-in option in the Offers dropdown.

If you've already signed up for Partner Center, you can find information about creating a Developer account for Microsoft Office Store on the following page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/marketplace/open-a-developer-account#create-an-account-using-an-existing-partner-center-enrollment